# I have a nested group Angular form. I want to take the group's controls values and match the name of the controls to my JSON object

Tags: forms, angular, validation

I have a small contact form that I have built using Angular. I want to validate the form and change the form data to JSON object.

Here's my Form:

```html
<form [formGroup]="addContactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate >

    <div [hidden]="addcontactForm.submitted">

        <div class="modal-body" style="overflow: auto">

            <!-- create contact -->
            <div style="padding: 0 0px 0px 25px;margin-top:30px;">

                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <span *ngIf="ACname.invalid && (ACname.dirty || ACname.touched)" class="has-error">
                        <span *ngIf="ACname.errors.required">
                            Last Name is required.
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <!-- name -->
                    <div FormGroupName="ACname">
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:right" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': ACname.addContactFirstName.invalid && (ACname.addContactFirstName.dirty || ACname.addContactFirstName.touched) }">
                            <label class="col-sm-3" for="addContactFirstName">First Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input id="addFirstName"

                                       formControlName="addContactFirstName"
                                       class="form-control"
                                       placeholder="Enter First Name" />


                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:right" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': ACname.addContactLastName.invalid && (ACname.addContactLastName.dirty || ACname.addContactLastName.touched) }">
                            <label class="col-sm-3" for="addContactLastName">Last Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input id="addLastName"

                                       class="form-control"
                                       formControlName="addContactLastName"
                                       placeholder="Enter Last Name" />

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div FormGroupName="ACcontactMethod">
                        <!-- office phone -->
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:right" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': ACcontactMethod.addcontactForm.submitted && !ACcontactMethod.addContactOfficePhone.valid }">
                            <label class="col-sm-3" for="addContactOfficePhone">Office Phone</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input id="addofcPhone"

                                       type="text"
                                       class="form-control"
                                       formControlName="addContactOfficePhone"
                                       placeholder="Enter Office Number" />
                                <span *ngIf="addContactOfficePhone.invalid && (addContactOfficePhone.dirty || addContactOfficePhone.touched)" class="has-error">
                                    <span *ngIf="addContactLastName.errors.required">
                                        Name is required.
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- mobile phone -->
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:right" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': addcontactForm.submitted && !addContactMobilePhone.valid }">
                            <label class="col-sm-3" for="addContactMobilePhone">Mobile Phone</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input id="addmobPhone"

                                       type="text"
                                       class="form-control"
                                       formControlName="addContactMobilePhone"
                                       placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" />
                                <span *ngIf="addContactMobilePhone.invalid && (addContactMobilePhone.dirty || addContactMobilePhone.touched)" class="has-error">
                                    <span *ngIf="addContactMobilePhone.errors.required">
                                        Name is required.
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- home phone -->
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:right" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': addcontactForm.submitted && !addContactHomePhone.valid }">
                            <label class="col-sm-3" for="addContactHomePhone">Home Phone</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input id="addhomPhone"

                                       type="text"
                                       class="form-control"
                                       formControlName="addContactHomePhone"
                                       placeholder="Enter Home Number" />
                                <span *ngIf="addContactHomePhone.invalid && (addContactHomePhone.dirty || addContactHomePhone.touched)" class="has-error">
                                    <span *ngIf="addContactHomePhone.errors.required">
                                        Name is required.
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- email -->
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:right" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': addcontactForm.submitted && !addContactEmail.valid }">
                            <label class="col-sm-3" for="addContactEmail">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input id="addEmail"

                                       type="email"
                                       class="form-control"
                                       formControlName="addContactEmail"
                                       placeholder="Enter Email" />
                                <span *ngIf="addContactEmail.invalid && (addContactEmail.dirty || addContactEmail.touched)" class="has-error">
                                    <span *ngIf="addContactEmail.errors.required">
                                        Name is required.
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- chat id -->
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:right" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': addcontactForm.submitted && !addContactChatId.valid }">
                            <label class="col-sm-3" for="addContactChatId">Chat ID</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input id="addChatID"

                                       type="text"
                                       class="form-control"
                                       formControlName="addContactChatId"
                                       placeholder="Enter Chat ID" />
                                <span *ngIf="addContactChatId.invalid && (addContactChatId.dirty || addContactChatId.touched)" class="has-error">
                                    <span *ngIf="addContactChatId.errors.required">
                                        Name is required.
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" (click)="addcontactForm.reset()" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    [disabled]="!addcontactForm.valid"
                    (click)="addContact(model);">
                Add Contact
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="submitted-message" *ngIf="addcontactForm.submitted">
        <p>You've submitted your contact, {{ addcontactForm.value.addContactFirstName }} {{ addcontactForm.value.addContactLastName }}!</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" (click)="addcontactForm.reset()" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button (click)="addcontactForm.resetForm({})">Add new Contact </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's my ts:

```ts
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent  } from '../app.component';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'addcontactmodal',
    templateUrl: 'addcontact.component.html'
})


export class AddContactModalComponent {
    id: any;

    addContactForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _appComponent: AppComponent, private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.id = localStorage.getItem('Id');

        this.addContactForm = this.fb.group({
            ACname: new FormGroup({
                addContactFirstName: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(40)),
                addContactLastName: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(40)),
            }),
            ACcontactMethod: new FormGroup({
                addContactOfficePhone: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(20)),
                addContactMobilePhone: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(20)),
                addContactHomePhone: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(20)),
                addContactEmail: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(127)),
                addContactChatId: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(127))
            })

        });
    }





    // private method(s)
    private addContact() {

        let data = {
            ChatId: this.fb.group('addContactChatId').value,
            Email: addContactEmail,
            FirstName: addContactFirstName,
            HomePhone: addContactHomePhone,
            MobilePhone: addContactMobilePhone,
            LastName: addContactLastName,
            OfficePhone: this.model.addContactOfficePhone
        }





        this._appComponent.signalRService.setAgentContact(this.id, data);          
    }  

}
```

I want to:

1. Validate the form
2. Have the data output to JSON

I do not get any of the validation the form promises. It doesn't submit.

Errors:

```
nhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined
    at Object.View_AddContactModalComponent_0.co [as updateDirectives]
```

Comment: Please read [mcve], then provide one.

Comment: hey, did the answer help you? :)

Comment: It did not. I am still confused on how to handle this. I'm not sure if I need more information or not

Answer (score 0):

You are not using complete property paths for your validation messages. Here's a simplified template of yours:

```html
<form [formGroup]="addContactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate >
 <!-- formGroupName - mark all form controls belonging to this group inside tag -->
 <div formGroupName="ACname">
  <input formControlName="addContactFirstName" />
  <!-- use complete property path or do like follows! -->
  <span *ngIf="addContactForm.hasError('minlength', 'ACname.addContactFirstName')">
   Minlength 40
  </span>
 </div>
</form>
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-geamm2?file=app/app.component.ts)**